# How to prevent dates before today in a material Calendar ? (Angular 9)

Tags: angular, luxon

I used Angular Material Calendar for a project and tried to prevent the selection of dates before today so I tried a  [min] constratint but that doesn't do the trick with a luxon creation of today's date so each day, the minimal date moves according to the good day.

Is there a good way to do it?
I have my calendar isolated here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-swrr7s?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/date-range-picker-overview-example.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following approach could solve your issue:

In .ts file

```
//today's date
todayDate:Date = new Date();
```

In .html file

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [min]="todayDate" placeholder="Date" formControlName="date"> 
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was so close but so far and you made me complete the gap. Many thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

In your stackblitz it doesn't work because Date.now() returns a number with a number of miliseconds and not a date object. If you change your code to:

```
today = new Date();
```

Concerning luxon - that will probably not work out-of-the-box, since there are only two built-in date adapters: `MatNativeDateModule`  and `MatMomentDateModule`. You will have to [create your own DateAdapter](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings) that would work with luxon - it's pretty well documented in the datepicker docs. You should be able to base yours on the moment one since luxon seems to borrow a bit from moment.

Comment: Thanks. I heard moment was abandoned and looked for information and luxon seemed like the successor of moment (since it was one of its maintainer who created luxon). I have to look what is a DateAdapter to fully undersstand what you mean.

Comment: A quick search - seems there's a public gist [here](https://gist.github.com/maburdi94/9500d90febb3caa519c3f2f8e996f9dc). Wish I could help more, but I'm still comfortable with moment.js :)